# React-native Protected member is not accessible when using this.setState()

Tags: react-native, protected, setstate

I am new to react native. Please help to solve this. where i have been wrong ? please point out and correct me.. Thank you so much

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Alert,View,Image} from 'react-native';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import {Button} from "../components/common";

class ImageSelect extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    state = {
        ImageSource: null,
        imageBase: null,
        whichScreen: null,
    };


    showPicker() {
        const options = {
            quality: 1.0,
            maxWidth: 500,
            maxHeight: 500,
            storageOptions: {
                skipBackup: true,
                path: 'images'
            }
        };

        ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
                console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
                console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else if (response.customButton) {
                console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
            }
            else {
                let source = {uri: response.uri};

                // You can also display the image using data:
                // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

                Alert.alert(source);
                this.setState({
                    imageSource: source
                });
            }
        });
    };

    showAlert(){
        Alert.alert("Picked");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    buttonText={"Pick"}
                    onPress={this.showPicker.bind(this)}
                />
                <Image
                    source={this.state.imageSource}
                    style={{width: 50, height: 50,}}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default ImageSelect;
```

I want to pick the image using existing library Image Picker.. and I need to save the source to the state but it says **Protected Member is not accessible** . Please point out where am i wrong?

Comment: You didn't call `showPicker ` method. So how does this error appear?

Comment: even i dont know how does this error appear ?

Comment: You get this error when you click the `button`?

Comment: For people stumbing here, if renaming your component is an option, you can do it. Somewhere in the libraries that guy has another `ImageSelect` component, that's the case when WebStorm errs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the state variables inside the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.showPicker = this.showPicker.bind(this);
this.state = {
  imageSource : null,
}
}
```

Also the onPress{} method inside Button is empty, you need to call that showPicker() function inside onPress{}, if that's where you desire to call it.

Comment: i have edited my code .. please review it and thanks for the response sir .

Comment: Bro you need add your state variables inside constructor, like the above code that i have posted.

Comment: pls update your code, and call like this `onPress={this.showPicker}`

Comment: i got error : when
this.setState({
    imageSource: source
});

IDE says. Protected member isnot accessible

Comment: I too am getting this error on Webstorm 2018.1, which was not occuring before. I have hundreds of js files that I am positive are properly using this.setState(), with binding in the constructor when necessary for scope.

Comment: I have the same problem on Webstorm 2018.1, Does anybody know what's the matter?